# Get the selected value from a combobox C#

Tags: c#

I have read through a bunch of topic on this subject. I've tried a lot of variations, but for some reason, I can't get this to work. Here's the problem: I have a combobox that is populated with the sheet names from an Excel workbook. (I'll include that code, in case the problem is there) When I try to get the selected text value, I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
    /********************************************************************************
     * The following code takes in an excel filename and populates a combobox based 
     * on the excel tab names.
     ********************************************************************************/
    private void GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFile)
    {
        _Application xlApp;
        Workbook xlTemplateWB;

        xlApp = new ApplicationClass();

        xlTemplateWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Elmnt.getDBPath() + TEMPLATENAME, 0, true,
            5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        foreach (Worksheet temp in xlTemplateWB.Worksheets)
        {
            cboBenchSheets.Items.Add(temp.Name);
        }

        xlTemplateWB.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        xlApp.Quit();
    }

    /********************************************************************************
     * This returns the selected item in the cboBenchSheets combo box
     ********************************************************************************/
    public String getSelection()
    {
        String selected;
        selected = cboBenchSheets.Text;                                         //Returns nothing
        selected = cboBenchSheets.SelectedText;                                 //Returns nothing
        selected = cboBenchSheets.SelectedValue.ToString();                     //Returns nothing
        selected = cboBenchSheets.GetItemText(cboBenchSheets.SelectedIndex);    //Returns -1

        return selected;
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't answer your question but if your commenting your code that way, you should stop. comment your code with `///` and use the `<summary>` nodes to place your comments in

Comment: When you're debugging, do any of those statements you're assigning to `selected` have a value? You're overwriting the variable's value every time you assign - what's the purpose of doing that? Is it just testing to see which each property contains? Stepping through in debug would be easier.

Comment: Please provide us with the code to _populate your cboBenchSheets_. Furthermore could you include the **call to getSelection()** in your answer, please

Comment: only the last one, which returns -1

Comment: When do you call `getSelection()`? I imagine the four `cboBenchSheets.*` values only get populated if the user actually selects an item in the combobox. You probably need to implement this into a `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: The code to populate the combobox is the first section. I tested each of the variations with messagebox.show(selected)

Answer (score 2):

I think this section of the [documentation for ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx) may help:

> You can use the SelectedText property to retrieve or change the
>   currently selected text in a ComboBox control. However, you should be
>   aware that the selection can change automatically because of user
>   interaction. For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a
>   button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is
>   because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus
>   moves from the combo box to the button.
>
> When the combo box loses focus, the selection point moves to the
>   beginning of the text and any selected text becomes unselected. In
>   this case, getting the SelectedText property retrieves an empty
>   string, and setting the SelectedText property adds the specified value
>   to the beginning of the text.
>
> When the combo box gains focus, the full text in the control is
>   automatically selected. If you call the control's Focus method to set
>   the input focus, the full text is selected regardless of whether the
>   control already had focus. When the user selects an item from the
>   drop-down list or by using the UP ARROW and DOWN ARROW keys, the text
>   for the new item is automatically selected. However, if you try to get
>   the SelectedText value in a SelectedIndexChanged or
>   SelectedValueChanged event handler, the property returns an empty
>   string. This is because, at the time of these events, the previous
>   SelectedText value has been cleared and the new value has not yet been
>   set. To retrieve the current value in a SelectedIndexChanged or
>   SelectedValueChanged event handler, use the SelectedItem property
>   instead.

Comment: It is good to know that when the combobox loses focus the selection point moves to the beginning. But, this still doesn't tell me how to retrieve the selected text. I just tried adding cboBenchSheets_SelectedIndexChanged() with cboBenchSheets.Focus(); and selected = cboBenchSheets.SelectedValue.ToString(); that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that you don't have an item selected, which is why all attempts to return a selected item return nothing. Does `selected = cboBenchSheets.Items[1].ToString()` return anything? This should help narrow the problem down

Comment: I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. What does that mean?

Comment: That normally means that you have tried to access an index that doesn't exist---does `selected = cboBenchSheets.Items[0].ToString()` work? It sounds like your combobox isn't actually being populated in the way you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you populate a combo box with items and don't do anything else with it, then it has no selected item until a selected item is explicitly set either by the user or in code.  I know this seems odd as the combo box appears to select the first item by default, but that's just the way it is.

Try setting the selected item to the first item manually after your for loop that populates the combo box's items collection.

```
foreach (Worksheet temp in xlTemplateWB.Worksheets)
{
    cboBenchSheets.Items.Add(temp.Name);
}

cboBenchSheets.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: The purpose of the form is to list the sheets in a workbook and save a copy of the selected sheet as a separate workbook. I have all of the code to save the sheet working (when the sheet name is hard coded), but I can't retrieve the sheet name from the combobox. the form I have built has the combobox, an ok button and a cancel button. When the ok button is clicked, it checks to make sure that the selected value != null and then (should) procede with opening the worksheet. Right now, I can't retrieve the selected text. I just need to know what the correct syntax is.  Thank you.

Comment: I understand. What I'm saying is that if the form loads and neither the user nor your code change the state of the combo box after you populate it, then it will not have a selected value even though it looks like the first item is selected by default.  You must explicitly set a default selected value after you populate the items collection.  Once a selected value has been set then you should be able to use cboBenchSheets.SelectedValue to get the selected value.

Comment: Right. I am selecting a value and then clicking the ok button.